# Regression line behaving strangely in seaborn/matplotlib chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is there a better way of plotting a function along a scatterplot in seaborn/matplotlib? I am just doing regplot, but for some reason the regression line is just doing... that.

Bonus question: is there a way I can have seaborn tell me what function its using for the line?

I really just need a line and an actual function the best way possible with these dots.

Thanks

```
a = { 4:44, 8:167, 16:479, 32:1239, 64: 2991, 128: 7012, 256: 15997, 512: 35922, 1024: 79590, 2048: 174699, 4096:380155,
8192: 821857, 16384: 1766870, 32768: 3779259, 65536: 8050043, 131072:17983451, 262144: 36133203, 524288: 76198683,
1048576:160262930, 2097152: 336255735, 4194304: 703966918, 8388608: 1470850124, 16777216: 3067526261, 33554432: 6386708998}



df = pd.DataFrame({'n':list(a.keys()), 'operations':list(a.values())})
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
ax.set(xscale="log", yscale="log")

ax= sns.regplot('n', 'operations', df, ci=None)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason why you are applying a log on both x and y?

Comment: The question on homework recommends it for readability. Probably for the grader.

Answer (score 0):

This shows only, that your regression line is not going through the origin (0, 0).

You can retrieve the slope and Offset of a polynomial fit of first degree by numpy's

```
import numpy as np
k = np.polyfit(df['n'], df['operations'], 1)
```

and plot it like

```
plt.plot(df['n'], df['n']*k[0]+k[1])
```

However, this will lead to (nearly) the same Picture.
But with polyfit you have the opportunity to weight the Points of your data.
And if you give the origin e.g. 1000 and the rest 1, you get a line going through (0, 0).

Comment: I ended up just doing 
t = np.arange(1, 2**25.)
m=np.log10(t)*t*18. AKA plotting a line just with numpy